# tizk aligning arc between nodes + same length

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, edge

I draw a graph where vertices are located on a grid.
I have horizontal and vertical arcs between some adjacent vertices which I would like to be horizontal or vertical. In addition arcs should have the same size.
Here is an example, where some arcs are not completely horizontal (and do not have the same size).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fff}{\mathrm{f}}
\newcommand{\iii}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\ooo}{\mathrm{o}}
\newcommand{\sss}{\mathrm{s}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathrm{p}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\scriptsize,anchor=base}]
\node (ooi) at (0,0)  {$\ooo\ooo\iii$};
\node (oos) at (1,0)  {$\ooo\ooo\sss$};
\node (oof) at (1,-1) {$\ooo\ooo\fff$};
\node (oop) at (0,-1) {$\ooo\ooo\ppp$};
\draw[->] (ooi) -- (oos);
\draw[->] (oop) -- (oof);
\draw[->] (ooi) -- (oop);
\draw[->] (oos) -- (oof);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can probably solve alignment issues with a node matrix. There are several questions on this sites with nice answers on the topic.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you place your nodes using the "left", "below", etc. directives, instead of absolute coordinates.

Comment: why did someone remove the previous proposed solution which was using phantom?

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu ... I had not take care about the lengths and there was not any reason to have same length as I gave it ... It was just about the alignment ... (an addition of minimum size could solve that too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fff}{\mathrm{f}}
\newcommand{\iii}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\ooo}{\mathrm{o}}
\newcommand{\sss}{\mathrm{s}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathrm{p}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum width=.65cm,minimum height=0.65cm,font=\scriptsize}]
\node (ooi) at (0,0)  {\vphantom{/fp}$\ooo\ooo\iii$};
\node (oos) at (1,0)  {\vphantom{/fp}$\ooo\ooo\sss$};
\node (oof) at (1,-1) {\vphantom{/fp}$\ooo\ooo\fff$};
\node (oop) at (0,-1) {\vphantom{/fp}$\ooo\ooo\ppp$};
\draw[->] (ooi) -- (oos);
\draw[->] (oop) -- (oof);
\draw[->] (ooi) -- (oop);
\draw[->] (oos) -- (oof);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler way of achieving a similar thing as the `\vphantom`, without having to modify each node, is to change the `every node` style to `every node/.style={font=\scriptsize\strut,anchor=base}` (adding the `\strut`).

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to draw this is IMHO to use `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\fff}{\mathrm{f}}
\newcommand{\iii}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\ooo}{\mathrm{o}}
\newcommand{\sss}{\mathrm{s}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathrm{p}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={font=\scriptsize}}]
\ooo\ooo\iii \arrow[r] \arrow[d]& \ooo\ooo\sss \arrow[d]\\
\ooo\ooo\ppp \arrow[r]& \ooo\ooo\fff\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using relative `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\fff}{\mathrm{f}}
\newcommand{\iii}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\ooo}{\mathrm{o}}
\newcommand{\sss}{\mathrm{s}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathrm{p}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\scriptsize,anchor=base}]
    \node (ooi) at (0,0) [minimum height=1.5em] {$\ooo\ooo\iii$};
    \node (oos) [right=1.5em of ooi, minimum height=1.5em]  {$\ooo\ooo\sss$};
    \node (oof) [below=1.5em of oos, minimum height=1.5em] {$\ooo\ooo\fff$};
    \node (oop) [below=1.5em of ooi, minimum height=1.5em] {$\ooo\ooo\ppp$};
    \draw[->] (ooi) -- (oos);
    \draw[->] (oop) -- (oof);
    \draw[->] (ooi) -- (oop);
    \draw[->] (oos) -- (oof);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Four nodes in a square with arrows between them]